# Printf with typedef integers, especially 64bit

Tags: c, gcc, printf, typedef, stdint

Consider this code:

```
typedef int64_t Blkno;
#define BLKNO_FMT "%lld"
printf(BLKNO_FMT, (Blkno)some_blkno);
```

This works well and fine on x86. On x64, int64_t is actually a `long`, rather than a `long long`, and while `long` and `long long` are the same size on x64, the compiler generates an error:

> src/cpfs/bitmap.c:14: warning: format ‘%lld’ expects type ‘long long int’, but argument 6 has type ‘Blkno’

1. How can I tell `printf` that I'm passing a 64bit type?
2. Is there some better way to standardize specs for user types than using a `#define` like `BLKNO_FMT` as above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `PRId64` from [`inttypes.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inttypes.h).

`Blkno` is not a very good type name. `BLKNO_FMT` could be replaced by `PRIdBLKNO`.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int64_t Blkno;
#define PRIdBLKNO PRId64

int main(void) {
  printf("%" PRIdBLKNO "\n", (Blkno)1234567890);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `(Blkno)` cast is pointless if you have used the right format specifier.

Comment: It's not pointless, integer arguments to a variadic functions are not promoted to long long.

Comment: @user502515: Without `(Blkno)` the compiler produces `'warning: conversion specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]'`

Comment: @user502515: See C99 §6.3.1.1/2 and §6.5.2.2/6 regarding integer promotions and *default argument promotions*.

Comment: The cast is to demonstrate that some_blkno is of type Blkno. I was not under the impression that the cast was actually necessary. If this is incorrect, please let me know!!

Comment: I'll add that in @J.F. Sebastion's example, the cast **is** necessary, as the literal is an int. However some_blkno is of type Blkno already, the cast should not be necessary.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: Blkno looks like čtvrthrst at a glance; both are pronounceable once deciphered.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastion: I've spent far too many hours trying to come up with the perfect variable and type names, now I just use whatever seems reasonable and quick and lengthen them only as required.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: There are only two hard things in CS: cache invalidation and naming things (by Phil Karlton http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)

Comment: @Matt Joiner: To paraphrase The Zen of Python: If the thing is hard to name, it's a bad abstraction. If the thing is easy to name, it may be a good abstraction. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Agreed on CS and Python statements. I don't know what you mean by čtvrthrst. Is your name a reference to Blade Runner?

Answer (score 0):

These types are not 64-bit types. They're platform-specific. The only portable way to print them is to cast to `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t` and use the correct format specifiers for to print those types.

Comment: Indeed, I assumed OP was working with POSIX filesystem-related types. If OP defined the type to be 64-bit then of course it's 64-bit.. :-)